# ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer[-fpermissive](C++)

Tags: c++

```
void first_screen_output()
{
    int input_num(); 
    scanf("%d",&input_num);
    if(input_num==1) return;
    else if(input_num==2)
    {
        system("pause");
    } 
}
```

when I tried to compiled this code, the error occurred.
the error occurred on if~else line. How can I solve this error?

Comment: why you have () in `int input_num();`

Comment: Remove the parentheses: `int input_num;`.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> int input_num();
> ```

This declares a **function** called `input_num` which returns an `int` and takes no arguments. Informally called ["the most vexing parse"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work). The fact that C++ allows you to declare functions inside of the implementation of other functions only adds to the confusion.

> ```
> scanf("%d",&input_num);
> ```

`"%d"` means that you want to read into an `int`, so you need to pass an `int*`. `&input_num`, however, is a **function pointer** (`int (*)()`), as your compiler should have warned you. That's because specifying a function name without parentheses (`input_num`) indicates a function pointer (and the address-of operator `&` has no effect here because function pointers are different from all other pointers).

So this line would result in undesired behaviour anyway.

> ```
> if(input_num==1) return;
> else if(input_num==2)
> ```

Function pointers cannot be compared with `int`s.

---

The solution to all these problems is actually making `input_num` an `int` and not a function:

```
int input_num = 0;
```

While you're at it, get rid of `scanf` and use `std::cin`.